# Is there a way to check 3 arrays from 1 json file in the same for loop?

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm trying to add alt names for Pokemon in a .json file to use in my command. The way I have it works just fine, but I was curious if there was any other way to search through 3 different arrays from the .json file without having to do 3 for loops? I tried adding an || but it sent an error. This is the way I currently have it:

````
for (var i = 0; i < names.Bulbasaur.length; i++) {
    if (msg === names.Bulbasaur[i].toLowerCase()) {
      if (toggle === 0) return message.channel.send(venusaur);
      if (toggle === 1) return message.channel.send("```" + venusaur + "```");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < names.Ivysaur.length; i++) {
    if (msg === names.Ivysaur[i].toLowerCase()) {
      if (toggle === 0) return message.channel.send(venusaur);
      if (toggle === 1) return message.channel.send("```" + venusaur + "```");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < names.Venusaur.length; i++) {
    if (msg === names.Venusaur[i].toLowerCase()) {
      if (toggle === 0) return message.channel.send(venusaur);
      if (toggle === 1) return message.channel.send("```" + venusaur + "```");
    }
  }
````

Comment: I suggest you write a function that accepts an array as a parameter.

Comment: `if ([...names.Bulbasaur, ...names.Ivysaur, ...names.Venusaur].some(name => name.toLowerCase() === msg)) ...`

Comment: Ah ok thank you so much

Comment: @lollipop Chris is suggesting an alternate way to write your `if` statement.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can minimize the amount of duplicated code by writing a function that accepts an array as a parameter along with any other required values:

````
function sendMessage(array, msg, toggle, venusaur) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (msg === array[i].toLowerCase()) {
      if (toggle === 0) return message.channel.send(venusaur);
      if (toggle === 1) return message.channel.send("```" + venusaur + "```");
    }
  }
}
````

Now you can call this with each array:

```
sendMessage(names.Ivysaur, msg, toggle, venusaur)
```

When you find yourself copy/pasting code and making a few minor changes, you should always consider writing a function instead. Note that this change only decreases the amount of code you write. It doesn't decrease the amount of looping that is executed. In other words, it is no less efficient at run time.

Alternatively, you can write the inner `if` condition to check all possibilities. A simplistic option is to use the `||` operator:

```
if (
    msg === names.Bulbasaur[i].toLowerCase() ||
    msg === names.Ivysaur[i].toLowerCase() ||
    msg === names.Venusaur[i].toLowerCase()
)
```

This change truly reduces the amount of looping and is more efficient. I still suggest wrapping the single loop in a function for organizational purposes.

Caveat: Reducing the code to a single for loop by introducing the if condition given above, assumes that all of the arrays are the same length.

Comment: I'm honestly really confused about all of this. Sorry I probably sound a bit dumb considering you explained it what seems to be in depth; my only issue is that the 3 arrays that I'm checking can be of different lengths so I wasn't sure how to loop the length of the arrays based on varying lengths. Is what you wrote above able to handle that?

Comment: @lollipop "my only issue is that the 3 arrays that I'm checking can be of different lengths" This is a crucial fact and means you won't be able to condense all three loops into a single loop like I suggest with the code that creates one long if condition. But you can use the first code snippet, because the loop uses the length of the passed in array. If that example still confuses you, I suggest that you read more about functions in JavaScript. They are a powerful tool to help you organize code and reduce duplication from copy/pasting all the time.

Comment: Ok thank you! The part about them being 3 different lengths is what I assumed about not being able to condense them but you've been very helpful, so thank you so much!!

Comment: @lollipop On the other hand, there's no need to write essentially the same code over and over. That's what functions are for. When you find yourself copying some lines of code and making small changes you should immediately consider putting those lines in a function instead. If you are not familiar with functions in JavaScript, then you definitely need to learn about them.